# Fetch Api, Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, fetch, cors

Tengo una api corriendo en `localhost` y realizo la peticion desde un archivo `Javascritp`.

La peticion es la siguiente :

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/user/',{
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true 
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                return response;
            })
            .then(function (myJson) {
                console.log(myJson);
            });
```

Y lo que me retorna es el `response`, con la siguiente data:

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: null
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
__proto__: Response
```

Aqui la petición GET en Express:

```
const express =require ('express');
const router =express.Router();

const mysqlConnection = require ('../database');

router.get('/user/',(req,res)=>{
    res.header({
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'mode':'no-cors'
    })
    mysqlConnection.query('Select * From user',(err,rows,fields)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.json(rows);
        }else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    })
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Si estás casi seguro, ¿Porqué no intentas agregar la cabecera CORS adecuada del lado del backend?

Comment: checate tu configuracion de CORS del lado del backend, o añade indica que framework estas utilizando en el backend para poder ayudarte

Comment: En primer lugar, la url que indicas: `http://localhost:3000/user/` no tiene un endpoint directo, es decir tu no estas indicando ni el nombre del archivo ni la extension de este por lo tanto es como si le dijeras al PC que hiciera un fetch hacia un directorio entero y no hacia un archivo especifico, ese es uno de los problemas, en segundo lugar, las cabeceras de acceso no se pueden establecer desde el frontend, por lo tanto las dos ultimas propiedades que tienes en el objeto `headers` son inutiles y no tienen sentido que se coloquen.

Comment: En segundo lugar le pones como `mode` a `fetch`, `no-cors` pero mas adelante usas cabeceras `CORS` dentro de tu propiedad `headers` como por ejemplo `Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` y `"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true` por lo que tu mismo estarias contradiciendo el uso de `no-cors`. una cosa mas que hay que explicar es que solo el backend tiene el derecho de quitar asignar `CORS` ademas estas se asignan a cada archivo en especifico donde requieras modificarlas,  por lo que esas `CORS` deberian ir enrealidad en un archivo `.php` (si usas php) o lo que sea que uses de backend.

Comment: Estoy utilizando NodeJs ,Express para crear la API y React del lado del Frontend

Comment: Entonces te sugiero usar el módulo [CORS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) de `npm`. Verifica la documentación, es muy fácil de usar, en desarrollo podrías hacerlo funcionar con solo 2 líneas: `const cors = require('cors');` y luego una vez que creas la instancia de la aplicación de Express, usas: `app.use(cors());`. Con eso ya debería funcionar cualquier petición.

Comment: Si es asi edita tu pregunta y añade el codigo de node y express para poder indicarte donde añadas y que es lo que necesitas para habilitar CORS

Comment: Por último, comentarte que los encabezados [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) y [`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) son cabeceras de respuesta, por lo tanto no hacen nada en tu solicitud `fetch`. Saludos

Comment: @Riven, el `endpoint` indicado por el OP es correcto, no necesita poner un nombre de archivo ni extensión. Es una API que (por lo visto en la pregunta ya editada) devuelve un JSON. Saludos

Comment: Veo que recibes un JSON (es lo que manda tu app), en el primer método `then` de `fetch` debes usar el parser JSON: `return response.json();` para que efectivamente el segundo método `then` reciba el JSON ya *parseado*. Verifica eso y comenta el resultado.

Comment: @MauricioContreras, tu respuesta fue la indicada. Del resto aprendi realmente bastante.